# SDN OpenDayLight (Aluminium SR2) SDN Link State Family

Tags: sdn, opendaylight

I have established a PCEP session between ODL (Aluminium SR2) and a vMX router.
I'm now following instructions on ODL web page
"https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/bgpcep/en/latest/bgp/bgp-user-guide-linkstate-family.html#bgp-peer"

I've enabled the speaker instance using URL
"/rests/data/openconfig-network-instance:network-instances/network-instance=global-bgp/protocols"

I can verify this as follows
"curl  -u "admin:admin" -X GET  'http://localhost:8181/rests/data/openconfig-network-instance:network-    instances/network-instance=global-bgp/openconfig-network-instance:protocols'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'"

Next I want to setup BGP neighbors to PCC device
For this I'm using url
"/rests/data/openconfig-network-instance:network-instances/network-instance=global-bgp/openconfig-network-instance:protocols/protocol=openconfig-policy-types:BGP/bgp-poc/bgp/neighbors"

The problem I have is the curl command return 500 and the ODL logs show the following exception

08:16:14.274 WARN [qtp103460772-71] /rests/data/openconfig-network-instance:network-instances/network-instance=global-bgp/openconfig-network-instance:protocols/protocol=openconfig-policy-types:BGP/bgp-poc/bgp/neighbors
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: (http://openconfig.net/yang/network-instance?revision=2015-10-18)identifier=null

I'm guessing I have the syntax wrong in the CURL command, but I can't see why (bgp-poc is the name given in speker instance url)

The CURL command detailed in https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/bgpcep/en/latest/bgp/bgp-user-guide-linkstate-family.html#bgp-peer
"/rests/data/openconfig-network-instance:network-instances/network-instance=global-bgp/openconfig-network-instance:protocols/protocol=openconfig-policy-types:BGP/bgp-poc/bgp/neighbors"

seems to be wrong in some way. There seems to be an instance identifier missing. In my example I think the instance identifier is "bgp-poc"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this working. The issue I had was that the CURL command in the ODL documentation just didn't work i.e.
https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/bgpcep/en/latest/bgp/bgp-user-guide-linkstate-family.html#bgp-peer

/rests/data/openconfig-network-instance:network-instances/network-instance=global-bgp/openconfig-network-instance:protocols/protocol=openconfig-policy-types:BGP/bgp-poc/bgp/neighbors

What did work for me http://localhost:8181/restconf/config/openconfig-network-instance:network-instances/network-instance/global-bgp/openconfig-network-instance:protocols/protocol/openconfig-policy-types:BGP/bgp-poc/bgp/neighbors

as described in
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/manipulate-lsp-via-opendaylight-pcep-tao-liu/?articleId=6670488229575307264